# Правильное многопоточное клиент-серверное(чат) TCP/IP взаимодействие. C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность, клиент-сервер, .net-core, передача-данных

Помогите разобраться как лучше всего поступить в сложившейся ситуации, перед тем, как я начну писать и потом 100500 раз переписывать.
Есть уже реализованное мною многопоточное клиент-серверное взаимодействие(никакого UI, только тесты).
Какие фрагменты кода нужно будет добавить - напишите, пожалуйста, в комментах.
И есть основная "проблема", в кавычках - до конца не уверен, что это на самом деле проблема. Помимо стандартного взаимодействия по типу клиент-сервер(отправка сообщений) есть некий дополнительный функционал: к примеру, есть **event** и у клиента, и у сервера. Инициируется это событие тогда, когда приходит сообщение от сервера к клиенту, или от клиента на сервер. Это первый момент. Теперь появляется класс, который хранит сообщения от каждого клиента(пускай будет Хранилище сообщений клиента). Второй момент: типы, которые обрабатывают событие поступления сообщения на сервер, должны добавить это сообщение в Хранилище сообщений клиентов. А теперь к первому вопросу, по своей глупости я подумал(в ТЗ нет никаких четких инструкций на этот счет), что хранилище класса, отвечающего за хранение сообщений клиента, должно быть вот такого вида `Dictionary<TcpClient, List<String>>`, а теперь мне в голову ударила мысль, что оно(хранилище) должно быть вот такого вида `Dictionary<Client, List<string>>`. Но, тут, опять таки, начинают терзать смутные сомнения касательно вида `Dictionary<Client, List<string>>`. Почему? Потому что класс **Client** - серверный клиент, и он ничего не знает(и я не хочу, чтобы знал, стараюсь в SPR) про какие-то лишние моменты, не связанные с работой на сервере. То есть, у него нет ни единого поля, типа, имя, фамилия и т.д. Так вот я и думаю, что надо может, на худой конец создать структуру, к примеру, ***ClientStruct***, где поместить какие-то поля, связанные с конкретным клиентом: id тот же, и смело сделать хранилище вида `Dictionary<ClientStruct, List<string>>` 'Это был первый вопрос, чтобы задать второй, нужно разобраться сначала с этим. Спасибо.

Comment: Очень мало инфы и много воды. Ваша задача не ясна, Вы показываете только какую то часть. Не факт, что вам вообще тут нужно все в памяти хранить. Но я постараюсь угадать. Во первых, Dictionary не является потокобезопасной коллекцией, потому если у вас многопоточный сервер и вы не используете синхронизацию, то вам больше подойдет ConcurrentDictionary. List также не является многопоточной коллекцией, либо синхронизируйте к нему доступ, либо используйте ConcurrentBag.

Comment: Но и даже этого недостаточно, вам обязательно надо синхронизировать вставку ConcurrentBag в ConcurrentDictionary, чтобы не иметь состояние гонок и не потерять первое сообщение от клиента.

Comment: Что касается ключа, то если у вас есть id клиента и по нему вы можете клиента идентифицировать однозначно, вот этот id и используйте. Если это строка или число, то никаких проблем. Если это самописная структура, то не забудьте переопределить equals и hashcode методы.

Comment: Но вообще непонятно зачем вся эта морока, если после рестарта сервера вы потеряете все данные. Почему бы это все в бд не занести?

Comment: @tym32167, хранить данные исключительно в памяти(по ТЗ). Скажу честно, что это первый раз, когда пишу такого рода приложение(сетевое многопоточное), поэтому уже набил шишек, когда разбирался со всем этим. Там еще и беда с потоками(как правильно останавливать сервер, освобождать потоки клиентов и т.д. Это все я планировал спросить, но потом) . Собрав ваши сообщения задам следующий вопрос: коллекция будет типа ConcurrentDictionary<ClientStruct,  ?>. вместо ? раньше был List, но он не подходит. А подойдет тогда такой вариант ConcurrentDictionary<ClientStruct, ConcurrentBag<string>>?

Comment: Скажем так, `ConcurrentDictionary<ClientStruct, ConcurrentBag<string>>` намного будет наделжней, чем ваш предыдущий вариант. Но имейте ввиду, что само по себе наличие потокобезопасных коллекций не делает ваш код потокобезопасным. И ещё, в качестве сообщения я бы хранил не просто строку, а какой то класс, со свими полями, типа от кого сообщение, кому, дата, идентификатор.

Comment: ну и не забудьте, что `ClientStruct` должен переопределить equals и gethashcode

Comment: _хранить данные исключительно в памяти_ это должно быть очень жесткое и явно обоснованное требование. Потому что хранить в памяти все, что происходило к примеру за последний год (вы же не собираетесь каждый час сервер перезагружать?), это сомнительное мероприятие с риском потери всех данных в случае сбоя в электропитании или какой-нибудь критической ошибки.

Comment: Я вас понял. Но вы поймите, что вопрос, где будет храниться данные абсолютно второстепнен в этой задаче. Потому что первая и главная задача - написать потокобезопасное клиент-сервреное взаимодействие.

Comment: (см. первый комментарий к этому вопросу)